# How to create own java object in FTL

Tags: java, freemarker

I am new in FTL, I have to create my own java object in FTL. I can't create this object in my java code because I am writing a generic class. This class will pick-up FTL based on request type and format the data of specific type.

```
PlacementRequest request = new PlacementRequest(dataMap);
```

Could someone help me on it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create your own object in ftl you must have 2.3.23 or above.

You can create the object using below sample code :

Java code :

rootMap.put("objectConstructor", new freemarker.template.utility.ObjectConstructor());

and then you can code ftl as below

<#assign placementRequest = objectConstructor("com.xx.xx.PlacementRequest",newbrmapRecord.getMap("placement"))>